# Массивы. Вывод n элементов через каждые n элементов

Tags: python, массивы

Есть строка:

```
str = "abcdefghijkl"
```

Нужно вывести каждые `n` элементов, через каждые `n` элементов, начиная с `n` элемента.
При `n = 1`, результат будет следуйщий `"acegik"`
При `n = 2`, результат будет следуйщий `"bcfgjk"`
При `n = 4`, результат будет следуйщий `"defg"`

```
def my_slice(data, start, step):
    i = 0
    res = data[start - 1:start - 1 + step:step - 1]
    print(res)
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':

    str = 'abcdefghijkl'

    bits = [1, 2, 4, 8]
    i = 0

    for bit in bits:
        pos = bit - 1
        i = pos
        start = 0
        end = 0
        while start < end:
            print(str[start])
            start += 1
        print()
```

Comment: Покажите, что вы за целый день насидели!?

Comment: @Visman Я в общем пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм Хемминга. И этим способом хочу найти проверочные биты для контрольных битов. Единого кода по данной задаче нету, так как он работает не корректно и только для n = 1, n = 2. При значениях 4,8 ломается все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
def foo(text, n):
    items = []

    i = n - 1

    while True:
        try:
            for _ in range(n):
                items.append(text[i])
                i += 1

            i += n

        except IndexError:
            break

    print(''.join(items))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = "abcdefghijkl"
    foo(text, n=1)  # acegik
    foo(text, n=2)  # bcfgjk
    foo(text, n=4)  # defgl
```

Если не нужно неполное включение элементов (не кратное `n`), тогда нужно в цикле добавить проверку, и если следующая последовательность не влезет в число `n`, цикл завершится:

```
def foo(text, n):
    items = []

    i = n - 1

    while True:
        try:
            for _ in range(n):
                if i + n > len(text):
                    raise IndexError()

                items.append(text[i])
                i += 1

            i += n

        except IndexError:
            break

    print(''.join(items))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = "abcdefghijkl"
    foo(text, n=1)  # acegik
    foo(text, n=2)  # bcfgjk
    foo(text, n=4)  # defg
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Вроди оно. Там для 4,8 чуть не точно, но там уже я поправлю, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
n = 1

i = n - 1
while i < len(arr):
    for _ in range(n):
        if i < len(arr):
            print(arr[i])
        else:
            break
        i += 1
    i += n
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

void SpecialOutput(const std::string& str, unsigned n)
{
    unsigned counter(0);
    bool should_print(false);

    size_t strLen = str.size();
    for(unsigned idx = 0; idx < strLen; ++idx)
    {
        ++counter;
        if(counter % n == 0) {
            should_print = !should_print;
        }

        if(should_print) {
            std::cout << str[idx];
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string INPUT_STRING = "abcdefghijkl";
    SpecialOutput(INPUT_STRING, 1);
    SpecialOutput(INPUT_STRING, 2);
    SpecialOutput(INPUT_STRING, 3);
    SpecialOutput(INPUT_STRING, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

**Upd:**

```
Output:
acegik
bcfgjk
cdeijk
defgl
```

Comment: Правильный ответ выдает только для n = 1.

Comment: Так, кажется, не сложно самому додумать

Comment: Не получается у меня додумать если уж сюда написал

Comment: Проверил еще раз выходные значения, функция делает ровно то, что вам нужно